# how can I get the selector string of an HTML node element?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I am getting an HTML element. I want to do the inverse, from this HTML element, I want to get its selector string (something like this: `button#myButton`)

```
function onclicked(e){
 console.log(e.target);  // I get node HTML element
}
```

[image]

**suppose I don't know what the id or element is, I will only know this when I click on it.**

I need to get the selector string from `e.target` that is the same of the screenshot.

how can I do it?

```js
function onclicked(e){
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button id="myButton" onclick="onclicked(event)">click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need the "selector"?

Comment: Just retrieve the ID attribute then.

Comment: @epascarello in my real code, I need to save this string, since the reference of the HTML element is lost, but if I do document.querySelector(selector) I can get this HTML element

Comment: Why do you need the string?? You have the element already, there is zero reason to look it back up.

Comment: This `e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() + "#" + e.target.id` produce the desider output. but i don't get the point.

Comment: @epascarello as I say, in my real code I get the HTML element, but for some reason I can't access it, BUT I can access it if I do it with its respective selector string, that's why I need to save it.  Regardless of what I need, is it possible to get the selector string of this HTML element I am getting?

Comment: @yavgz please post real code "i can't " !== "web developer"

Comment: So that means you must be doing something like replacing the innerHTML... So read the id and look it up by that. Personally I would find out why you have a reference to the element and somehow that reference is destroyed.

Comment: @yavgz If you can get the HTML element, then can't you just use `element.tagName.toLowerCase() + "#" + element.id`?

Comment: @CharlesMasgalas how can get the selector from `e.target`

Comment: Two people showed you how to build it. There is no "getSelector" endpoint, you would need to build it like they have in their comments.

Comment: _I get the HTML element, but for some reason I can't access it, BUT I can access it if I do it with its respective selector string_ So, you managed to get it the first time. Can't you use the same selector? Was it selected the first time based on hierarchy, and that hierarchy is changed by DOM modifications?

Comment: If the modifications only _alter_ the DOM, e.g., by inserting or removing elements directly, then you could assign a `data-*` attribute (instead of deriving a selector string) and use that to select it. If whole portions of the DOM are changed/replaced (e.g., `innerHTML`), then you'll need to find something inherently unique to it that remains unchanged even after these modifications, such as an ID that is always present.

Comment: @yavgz What about `e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() + "#" + e.target.id;`? I think this does what you need but I'm still confused about what you're trying to do and why you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be completely transparent with you here, I'm not *entirely* sure what you're trying to achieve here. Considering you're using `document.querySelector` anyway, why aren't you storing the button there? Is there a problem with storing a reference to the actual DOM element as opposed to the query selector string?

I've *basically* written out a pseudo implementation which I believe provides an answer to your question. Despite the fact that I'm not very confident that I know what you're trying to do or *why* you want to do it this way.

I strongly recommend you take a look at what I've done & review it, my answer is **not** a work of art, rather a simple solution to the problem. By all means provide some feedback if this answer *doesn't* provide the outcome you were looking for. I'm happy to help if I can!

```js
const log = console.log;

const cache = {
  element: undefined,
  selector: undefined
};

function onClicked(event) {
  log(event.target);
  const element = event.target;
  cache.element = element;
  cache.selector = element.tagName.toLowerCase() + '#' + element.getAttribute('id');
  log(cache);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onclick="onClicked(event)" id="myButton">click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```